# How can I retrieve items for a sub-table based on an item ID in the master table in a Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have a Razor Page view that simply generates a table of items from a List retrieved from a Model property, like so:

```
@page
@model Agency.Pages.TypeManagement.CategoryType.IndexModel

@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category[0].CategoryCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category[0].CategoryName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category[0].CategoryDescription)
        </th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Category) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CategoryId">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.CategoryId">Details</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CategoryId">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is to output a sub-table for each item in the table, if any items exist in the sub-table, based on the ID of the item in the master table. I know that I can use a property, like Model.Category, in a Razor statement, but is it also possible to retrieve data from the View based on the value of something like the ID of the current item?

So what I want to end up with is something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Category) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryCode)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDescription)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CategoryId">Edit</a> |
        <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.CategoryId">Details</a> |
        <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CategoryId">Delete</a>
    </td>
    <table>
        <tbody>
@foreach (var subitem in Model.SubCategory) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subitem.CategoryCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subitem.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subitem.CategoryDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@subitem.CategoryId">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@subitem.CategoryId">Details</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@subitem.CategoryId">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
        </tbody
    </table
</tr>
}
```

But I need to filter the SubCategory items based on the ID of the item in the current row of the main table.

Comment: is there a property linking the two?

Comment: The SubCategory has a foreign key to the Category, which is the Category.Id

Comment: Filter subcategories on the current item.  `@foreach (var subitem in Model.SubCategory.Where(x => x.CategoryId = item.Id)` where `item` is from the outer `foreach` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter subcategories on the current item/row's identifier.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Category) {

    //...omitted for brevity

    var subItems = Model.SubCategory.Where(x => x.CategoryId = item.Id);
    if(subItems.Any()) {
        <table>
            <tbody>
        foreach (var subitem in subItems) {
            //...omitted for brevity
```

where `item` is from the outer `foreach` loop.

Reference [Using the Razor Syntax: Combining Text, Markup, and Code in Code Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c#combining-text-markup-and-code-in-code-blocks)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this approach. I didn't know I could use anything more than a simple property in the Razor @if statement. Where would I find documentation on what can be used in Razor statements? The official doc I found only shows the use of simple properties (usually an IList type).

Comment: It appears that this approach works, however, in my case, using the code I presented as an example, the '@' is not required on the 'var' or the 'if', or even the 'foreach' because the code is already inside of a Razor code block (the outer @foreach). At least that is what the code editor tells me. I added the code, as you suggested, without the leading '@' on the nested Razor code statements and everything compiled and ran just fine. Thank you @Nikosi for your help pointing me in the right direction.